# How to automate Magento shipping email?

Tags: magento-community, magento-1, magento-1.3

Hi I was wondering if anyone could guide me to automating the sending of the shipping email, which will outline the tracking number etc... telling the customers that their order is out for delivery.

As, I am currently understanding is that you click the little checkbox then press send. A step that could go un-noticed or missed by accident leaving customers unaware that their item(s) is/are out for delivery

Answer (score 0):

The order is not out for delivery when you create a shipment from the mangento backend. When you create a shipment you actually assign an airway bill no / tracking no to the shipment which you receive from your courier partner. Now you package your consignment and hand it over to your courier partner. Your courier partner then takes it to the customer. For tracking the consignment they generally provide an api which you can integrate on your site.

However, for sending an email automatically on shipment creation you can take help from the following link.

http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/tag/sales_order_shipment_save_after/

Comment: Sorry bit confused: so what would be the purpose of shipments ?